# jquery show div only if no results returned in search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that I need some guidance with please. I need the **#no-results** element to appear only if no results are found. Currently it shows **IF** results are found.

```
 $('#no-results').hide();
        $('#video-search-text').keyup(function () {
            $('.video-search').hide();
            $('#no-results').css("display", "none");
            var txt = $('#video-search-text').val(); 

            $('.video-search').each(function () {
                if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
                    $(this).show(); 

                }
                else {
                      $('#no-results').css("display", "block");

                }
            });

        });
```

I have created the following [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cvdqLuc7/) for convenience. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the check for no result from inside the for each loop, and place it after the search is complete. like

```
 $('#no-results').hide();
 $('#video-search-text').keyup(function() {
     $('.video-search').hide();
     $('#no-results').css("display", "none");
     var txt = $('#video-search-text').val();
     var resultCount = 0;
     $('.video-search').each(function() {
         if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
             $(this).show();
             resultCount++;
         }
     });

     if (resultCount == 0) {
         $('#no-results').css("display", "block");
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

James gave you a good solution. 
Basically, the problem comes from this loop

```
$('.video-search').each(function()
```

Suppose you search for 'abc' in your jsFiddle, it will find a match with the first `<h1>`.  This makes it enter your first block, so 'the results not found' will not be shown.

However, since you are looping for each element, it will compare 'abc' against 'def', and then enters the else block.  The same goes when comparing with 'ghi'.